# Jmeter alternative

Tags: performance, jmeter, grinder

I'm looking for a freeware / simpler alternative to JMeter. It is a very complete yet complex tool and all I need is to simulate a number of simultaneous calls to a site, grab stats about performance (time to the response) and see how many concurrent calls it can endure without breaking. Some chart thrown in would be useful.

Comment: recently i used http://locust.io/ hope it will solve your problem

Comment: There has been a [complete overview of all ~50 tools](https://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) done by Blazemeter.

Comment: OctoPerf has recently **fully tested** [20+ Alternatives to JMeter](https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/11/21/open-source-load-testing-tools/) including Gatling, K6, Locust, Tsung, The Grinder, SoapUI and more.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Use Apache Benchmark (ab). It's a command line tool that ships with apache web server. If you're running *nix, chances are it's already installed on your machine. For example, if you want to send 1000 requests to a web server running on localhost using 10 concurrent threads you would do this:

```
$ ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://localhost/
```

It'll spit out a nice report giving you interesting stats such as requests per second, number of failures, and much more.

Comment: if it's not already installed, you can install with sudo apt-get install apache2-utils

Comment: Apache bench covers the most basic case where you just want to bombard a single URL. If you want to do more realistic stress tests, I would recommend Locust (http://locust.io). It's an open-source load testing tool where you define your tests using python code.

Comment: For those who have realized that JMeter is not built for high loads, the choice is between locust.io and Gatling . Of the two, locust is the simpler one as you can get going in no time . Gatling has more possibilities and therefor more complex

Comment: If you are a command-line geek like me, this is perfect for you. For more info on how to use this: `man ab`. Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

Maybe you could try [Gatling](https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki) .

It provides a GUI, recorders, reports (response time distribution, requests per second over time,..),...

I think that the biggest difference between gatling and jmeter is that gatling does not use 1 thread for 1 user, but uses async IO. It could be interesting if you have performance issues whith jmeter (and if you cannot use jmeter in a distributed mode)

Answer (score 14):

Try [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/), it's reasonably simple to use, and can be scripted.

Comment: Grinder is as "complex" as jmeter. So i don't think it Will help.

Answer (score 7):

Try [FunkLoad](http://funkload.org/), a functional and performance testing tool for web apps, written in Python.

Comment: In addition to that, it requires test cases to be also written in python. In that case, i don't think so it will be viable alternative for jmeter

Answer (score 7):

Try jmeter + [jmeter plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) code.
It should be as simple as others.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmeterforwindows/

Answer (score 2):

Grinder, Funkload, SoapUI (only for Soap Services), Neoload (for load test), Charles Proxy

Comment: SoapUI can be used for REST too