# Open Source Load Testing for testing Asp.net application

Tags: jmeter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jmeter alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754427/jmeter-alternative)

Other than JMeter, whether there are any open source tool for load testing to test Asp.net applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, ab is pretty much the standard http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ApacheBench.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more tools http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server_benchmarking